# gap between lines notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ my text looks like this:

```
hello001
byebye
house
garden
```

What i want to do is to add an empty line between each pair of lines, so it looks like this:

```
hello001

byebye

house

garden
```

There are many lines and i don't want to do it one by one by clicking enter. Is there a command to do it with all selected lines?

Comment: no idea how to edit my original post.. i mean "add a free LINE" and not "like"

Comment: right below the tags of your question there is an `edit` that you can click...

Comment: If you want all the lines to have a blank line in between, the regex is this Find `(?m)\r?\n\s*^` Replace `\r\n\r\n` Fyi, a _blank_ line isn't `\r?\n`.

Comment: i used this one: (\r?\n) and it worked. how does it work, if it isnt blank?

Comment: _`If you want all the lines to have a blank line in between, the regex is this`_ ===

Comment: oh i see. so if i have also some blank lines, \r?\n wont regocnize them, so my already existing blank lines wont get another blank line? but with your command, all my existing lines, doesnt matter if they are blank or not, will get another blank line inbetween?

Comment: Please clarify if you need to add a newline character between lines with following more than one newline character or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this find and replacement in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
(\r?\n)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1$1
```

This will find all newlines in your document and replace them with two newlines.  Note that I use the pattern `\r?\n` to cover both Windows and Unix line endings (Windows uses `\r\n` while Unix uses just `\n`).  The trick here is that we capture the line ending, whatever it is, and then replace it with two of what we just captured.

Comment: You can use `\R` for platform independent linebreak matching. Can't you just match without capturing and use `$0` for the replacement?

Comment: If I'd downvote an answer and comment it in the same moment, my comment would usually start with _This is not a correct answer_, so no, I didn't.

Comment: i see. so looking for /r means its looking for line end. and line end is empty, so it will add empty new lines when you replace the capture with $1, right? thats a clever trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if regular expressions seem too fancy.

- <kbd>Ctrl+Home</kbd> (or manually put the cursor at the beginning of the first line)
- `Macro › Start Recording`
- <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>
- `Macro › Stop Recording`
- `Macro › Run a Macro Multiple Times... › Run until the end of file › Run`

(There are hotbar icons for all macro-related actions, you could use them instead of the menu if you want to.)

Note that it works with the entire file. If you wish to apply it to a part of a file only, you'll need a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `$`
- Replace with: `\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

This replaces end of line by linebreak.

**Result for given example:**

```
hello001

byebye

house

garden
```